# Trouble Running Cucumber with Stephen Celis config app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I'm trying to get cucumber up and running with a config app I use in Rails.

The config app is used to set various config options in Rails, for example the site value for ActiveResource:

```
self.site = "http://#{App['domain']}#{App['path']}"
```

When I run "cucumber features", I can get an error

```
bad URI(absolute but no path): http:// (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

I'm assuming this is because cucumber is not populating that self.site field with values from the config gem before it runs. I've included the config gem in my test environment but have not had any luck.

Where should I go from here?

The original app config gem is located here:

```
http://github.com/stephencelis/app
```

Comment: Some follow up testing with this. The self.site is only getting set with "http://" and nothing else. I don't get an error, I just get blank results.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this gem, but did notice that you said you included the config gem in your "test environment." If you haven't already done so, you should make sure you do the same in the config/environments/cucumber.rb file as well. This might not be your issues, but I've seen people get tripped on test versus cucumber environments several times in the past.

Comment: Yep, tested including it and not including it. It would trip an error when it was not present.

I've given up and just created a hash under my initializers that contains all my site options.